# Unable to toggle multiple dynamic Google Maps marker points with checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So, I've been trying to determine how to fix this problem for quite awhile now. I have a list of map points that are dynamically added with every update from the squad. 
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ch0chi/ngkq8dja/13/)

Here's an example of what each update would look like:

```
mapPoints.push(new google.maps.LatLng(33.730362 , -85.792725));
        names.push("Alpha");
        times.push("1425059747829");
        colors.push("Red");

        mapPoints.push(new google.maps.LatLng(33.7304572 , -85.792498));
        names.push("Alpha");
        times.push("1425059747829");
        colors.push("Red");

        mapPoints.push(new google.maps.LatLng(33.7304346 , -85.792634));
        names.push("Alpha");
        times.push("1425059747829");
        colors.push("Red");

        mapPoints.push(new google.maps.LatLng(33.73041 , -85.79264));
        names.push("Alpha");
        times.push("1425059172108");
        colors.push("Blue");

        mapPoints.push(new google.maps.LatLng(33.730312 , -85.792654));
        names.push("Delta");
        times.push("1425059747723");
        colors.push("Blue");



        mapPoints.push(new google.maps.LatLng(33.73023 , -85.79246));
        names.push("Foxtrot");
        times.push("1425059172145");
        colors.push("Purple");


        mapPoints.push(new google.maps.LatLng(33.72476 , -85.788185));
        names.push("Golf");
        times.push("1425050587395");
        colors.push("Green");
```

Based on this information, I pass each mapPoint into a google maps marker, and label them based on their names. I then update a dynamic checkbox based on the squad names given, removing duplicates. Now, whenever I try and toggle visibility of all points associated with a squad name it only removes one point instead of all of them. Any help would be very appreciated!

```
function updateCheckbox(names,markers){

var checkbox = $("#checkBoxes");

//check if names return null if names !=null create a dynamic list of  checkboxes
//based on live squads


if(names!=null){
var $ctrl = $('<input/>').attr({type:'checkbox', checked:'yes',name:'chk'});
$("#checkBoxes").append($ctrl);


//designate squad name to each checkbox
$ctrl.after(names);
console.log(names);
 // toggle display of the squads


 }


 $($ctrl).click(function () {
if (this.checked) {
    if (markers) {
        for (var i=0; i<markers.length;i++) {
            if(markers[i].labelContent==markers){
          markers.setVisible(true);
      }
        }
    }
} else {
    if (markers) {
        for (var i=0; i<markers.length;i++) {
            if(markers[i].labelContent==markers){
          markers.setVisible(false);

         }
                }
              }
           }
      });

       }
```

Comment: I don't see any checkboxes in the fiddle.

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/ngkq8dja/9/ I updated the link in the question as well.
I think it wasn't displaying due to the https tag. If it doesn't work try changing https to http.

Comment: @geocodezip did you manage to get the checkboxes in the JSFiddle to work?

Comment: Still don't see them.  I found two buttons and the text, but don't see any checkboxes.  Where are they supposed to be?

Comment: Forget to load the external markers as https. Here's the working link: https://jsfiddle.net/ch0chi/ngkq8dja/13/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You remove the duplicates, so they aren't associated with the checkbox.  Grouping the markers and looping through them when the checkbox is clicked will hide or show them all:

```
var squads = {};
//create a hash of squads
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    if (squads[names[i]] === undefined) {
        squads[names[i]] = {markers: [markers[i]]};
    } else {
        squads[names[i]].markers.push(markers[i]);
    }
}
for (squad in squads) {
    updateCheckbox(squad, squads[squad].markers);
}
...
$($ctrl).click(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setVisible(this.checked);
    }
});
```

[Updated fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/brendaz/3dzpcLwu/)

Comment: Worked like a charm! I had the same general idea, just wasn't sure on how to execute it. I can't thank you enough for helping me out!